# How to change Empathy appearance in 12.10?

Tags: 12.10, empathy, appearance

Since I updated to Quantal, I cannot modify Empathy's appearance. In particular,
I want Empathy to shows just the names and status icons of my contacts, without avatars and other stuff.

In the preferences preference there is no options to modify for this.

I tried editing the `gconf-editor` keys, but I did not obtain any changes.